Hibernate Migration from 5.6 to 6.6 - TIMESTAMP column is returned as JavaType Timestamp instead of Date
After migrating to Hibernate 6.6.1 Final, the DATETIME columns and TIMESTAMP columns in MySQL 8.0.36 are returned as Timestamp (Java type). What can be done to revert to the previous behavior (Hibernate 5). The field in the Entity is of type java.util.Date and on calling EntityManager.merge(entity) the return entity maintained the java type but now it is changed to Timestamp.
Per https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.5/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#java-time, the java times should be disbaled but I'm unsure why it is converted into Timestamp. I tried setting the below properties in the hibernate configuration.
hibernate.type.java_time_use_direct_jdbc=false
